# Can one know if $P(A \cap B) > P(A)P(B) $ or $P(A \cap B) < P(A)P(B) $?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I understand the following definition:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) $ if $A$ and $B$ are independent and

$P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)P(A)$ and $P(B|A)P(A)\neq P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

My question is:

> For the case of dependence, does $P(A \cap B) > P(A)P(B) $ or $P(A \cap B) < P(A)P(B) $ or is it not possible to know without any values ?

Comment: Both can be true. You need more information to know which of the two. Btw "$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent" is not a theorem but a definition.

Comment: thanks ! and also edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$, the equation $P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)$ is equivalent to $$P(B\mid A)>P(B)$$ (assume that $P(A)\neq 0$ to avoid trivial cases). This equation, says that: given that $A$ occured, $B$ has become more probable. For example, let $A$ be the event "there are clouds in the sky" and $B$ the event "it rains". Assume that you know from past data the probability $P(B)$ (perhaps you are a meteorologist). Now, knowing that $A$ applies (you open your window and you see many clouds outside), then certainly this increases the probability of $B$.

But it can also be the other way: let "A" be the event "there are no clouds in the sky" (you open your window and it is so sunny that you close it again). Then, certainly $P(B\mid A)<P(B)$.

Comment: great ! intuitive examples always helps

Answer (score 3):

There exists a rough estimate about $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A)P(B)$ whether events $A$ and $B$ are dependence or not, which is

$$ \left| P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B) \right| \leq \frac{1}{4} $$

The proof of this inequality can be proved by discussing the relationship of events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm a bit late to comment on this, but does anyone know a name for this inequality or a link to a proof?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this might help:

Assuming $\mathsf{P}(A)\neq 0,1$ and $\mathsf{P}(B)\neq 0,1$.

Consider the random variable $1_A$, where $1_A(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in A$ and $1$ if $\omega\notin A$.

Now $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)=\mathsf{E}(1_A\cdot 1_B)-\mathsf{E}(1_A)E(1_B)=\mathsf{E}(1_{A\cap B})-\mathsf{E}(1_A)\mathsf{E}(1_B)$

Now $\mathsf{E}(1_A)=1\cdot \mathsf{P}(A)+0\cdot \mathsf{P}(A^c)=\mathsf{P}(A)$

Hence $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)=\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)-\mathsf{P}(A)\mathsf{P}(B)$

So $\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)>\mathsf{P}(A)\mathsf{P}(B)$ implies $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)>0$ and $\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)<\mathsf{P}(A)\mathsf{P}(B)$ implies $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)<0$.

So $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)>0$ implies if $A$ occurs then it is more likely to $B$ also occurs or if $B$ occurs then it is more likely to $A$ also occurs.

Similarly, $\mathsf{Cov}(1_A,1_B)<0$ implies if $A$ occurs then it is less likely to $B$ also occurs or if $B$ occurs then it is less likely to $A$ also occurs.